# Hours of operations in different time zones

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, timezone

I posted a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923598/department-hours-of-operation-for-different-time-zones-in-sql-server

I think I added too much information to the post :)

What I am trying to do is display hours of operations in different time zones. I am having a difficult time figuring out how to display something like Mon - Fri: 630AM to 630PM (UTC -07:00 Arizona) in every other time zone. I'll get to a point (in another time zone) where Monday is no longer Monday...and I can't seem to figure out how to identify the change.

How do I convert a list of days (Monday, Tuesday, etc...) and Times to every other time zone and find the correct day to use?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a formatting issue, but rather a presentation issue - nothing is going to automatically translate availability into terms that make sense in other timezones. It would be better to give the availability (in its original terms) plus a timezone, rather than trying to convert it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had to make some modifications to how I am building the schedule. I was putting the cart before the horse.

Answer (score 1):

Time zones are all relative. Australian Eastern Standard Time is UTC+10 and Eastern Daylight Time is UTC+11. USA Eastern Standard Time is UTC-5 and Eastern Daylight Time is UTC-4. To go from 09:00 21 Dec 2012 Australian EDT to US EST is simply `DATEADD(h, -16, '09:00 21 Dec 2012')`. The only real trick is knowing when Daylight savings in each zone starts and stops and which juristictions it applies in (Daylight Savings is not observed in Queensland for example).

A google search on time zones will give you the info you need to determine where they sit relative to Universal Time (UTC).

The System.Globilization namespace has everything you could need for this. The datetime class has a lot of methods too.